# CSS border-radius property not working efficiently on Firefox browser

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-table, border-radius

I have set border-radius property with CSS to table element on my web page. This configuration is working successfully on Chrome, Opera and Edge. But there is some bug(I suppose) on Firefox like this:
[FirefoxImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yi8FK.png)

This unexpected corners is not appearing on other browsers.
On chrome like this:
[ChromeImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcryY.png)

My CSS codes for table:

```
    #projectList {
        position: relative;
        top: 5px;
        border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-style:solid;
        background-color:transparent;
    }
```

Table format on inspector:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hceSo.png)

Comment: Please add the necessary HTML that allows us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example forhelp with putting code into your question - not as an image though.

Comment: Do those lines come and go as you zoom in and out?

Comment: @AHaworth Ghost line sizing related table size while zoom or out. But I think I have solved the problem.  I have changed that border-style property as none.  As you see border-style was solid on my answer. Its really interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. I have changed that border-style property as none. As you see border-style was solid on my answer.

```
 #projectList {
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-style:none;
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

Its really interesting but it works.

Answer (score -1):

you need reset.css to fix browser default style

it is a group of style to clear browser default style, you can find many versions of reset.css on internet

Comment: Please explain what reset.css means here. And try out any solution you suggest before posting it as an answer. 'you may need...' is something that would fit better in a comment.

Comment: @AHaworth  I think I have solved the problem. I have changed that border-style property as none. As you see border-style was solid on my answer. Its really interesting.  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: It wasn't my answer!